# Split TD in different sections

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4

Sorry for the double post (2 hours ago), but it's still not working.

I am using a table from Bootstrap 4 for creating a tournament generator. The last part is that I give numbers to the games.

The part at the top is the situation right now. I want the situation from the bottom part, with 1 number in front of it.
[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hxw7.jpg)

This is my code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Quarter-finals</th>
      <th colspan="2">Semi-finals</th>
      <th colspan="2">Final</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><?php echo '<b>' . $player_1 . '</b><hr><b>' . $player_2 . '</b>' ;?></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="vs-text">Winners game 1 & 2</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="vs-text">Winners game 5 & 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><?php echo '<b>' . $player_3 . '</b><hr><b>' . $player_4 . '</b>' ;?></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="vs-text">Winners game 3 & 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><?php echo '<b>' . $player_5 . '</b><hr><b>' . $player_6 . '</b>' ;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><?php echo '<b>' . $player_7 . '</b><hr><b>' . $player_8 . '</b>' ;?></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
td, th {border: 1px solid black !important;}
hr {margin-top: 2px !important; margin-bottom: 2px !important;}
.vs-text{text-align: center; line-height: 45px; opacity:0.2;}
td{ padding: 1em; border: 1px solid; text-align: center;}
```

And this is how how the table looks like right now:

[Link to my table](https://imgur.com/a/e1jNU5V)

So, what I want is that there is a small number in a different small cell in front of every game. Anyone a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could add another `td` and use percentage `widths` to define the widths, for a responsive table.

```css
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }


    tr td:first-child {
      width: 20%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    tr td:last-child {
      width: 80%;
    }

    hr {
      background-color: #c7c7c7;
      height: 1px;
      border: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2<hr> 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ktLd136a/1)

Comment: It was however not working. I added more information. EDIT: So as you can see, the second TD isnt the last child.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is to use the attribute colspan/rowspan: If you want to have your suggested [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hxw7.jpg), try something like this:

```css
td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">1</td>
  <td>Speler 13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Speler 14</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```